# Check for End of File in Nodejs with line by line read

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am using `readline` to read line-by-line from a file and want to detect the end of the file.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
var readline = require('readline');

var rd = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'),
  output: process.stdout,
  console: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
  console.log(line);
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close), use `close` event

```
rd.on('line', function(line) {
console.log(line);
})
.on('close', function(line) {
 // EOF
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you can listen to `close` event to detect end of file

```
rd.on('close', function() {
   // end of file
})
```